# When should I attack the green dragon?

Tags: dragon-quest

I’m at level 9 and ran into the green dragon in a cave guarding something. He took me out in a couple hits. What level should I be at for a more successful encounter? Should I have any special items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the green dragon in the swamp cave in the original Dragon Quest, then you should

- be around lvl 11
- have a broadsword
- have full plate armor

In combat just hit him and heal, when your HP drops below 45.

Comment: I was at level 9 when I attempted. By the time I got your answer, I was at level 13 and defeated him easily.